# How to convert a List of urls to a list of Images?

Tags: flutter, dart, carousel

`widget.post['imageUrl']` has list of image `url`s.

When passing this `widget.post["imageUrl"][0]` I am only getting one image.

How can I check how many images a list has and show all together in this carousel?

```dart
List image = widget.post['imageUrl'];
Container(
  height: deviceHeight,
  child: Carousel(
    boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
    images: [
      Image.network(
        NetworkImage(image[0])
      )
    ],
  ),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
      bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The fix

In your code, instead of

```dart
images: [
  Image.network(
    NetworkImage(image[0])
    )
  ],
```

you could write ***something like***

```dart
images: widget.post['imageUrl'].map((e) => Image.network(e)).toList(),
```